# Lombok getter/setter generation wrong when first char lowerCase and next upperCase

Tags: lombok

I have a problem with generating getter/setter for attributes like xPos, yPos, nCounter and so on. 
Plattform is Eclipse Luna, Java 1.7, Struts2...

While Eclipse generates

```
private xPos

getXPos()
setXPos(...)
```

Lombok will generate

```
getxPos()
setxPos(...)
```

Is there any way to tell Lombok to uppercase every first character?

Comment: Lombok makes the first character uppercase: https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html . The problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, but only if there at least two chars before the first uppercase char.

Comment: "For generating the method names, the first character of the field, if it is a lowercase character, is title-cased, otherwise, it is left unmodified. Then, get/set/is is prefixed."  No mention of your "two chars" rule. @Getter int xPos; generates getXPos() for me as expected.

Comment: Lombok now generates it correct. Had in the meantime manually written the setter to become ready. Now I wanted to take another a look to this behaviour and now it works...

Comment: intellij as well will generate getxPos(), it's not a problem

Comment: I encountered a post here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503977/spring-mvc-jackson-mapping-query-parameters-to-modelattribute-lowercase-wi, if the problem is jackson mapper/marshaller of the rest api, try using @JsonProperty("xPos") annotation on the field. It fixed my issue.

Answer (score 4):

Even if the getter looks OK , you may need to force property name when this class is sent over the wire and converted to json for it

```
 @Setter(onMethod_ = {@JsonSetter("yResolution")})
 @Getter(onMethod_ = {@JsonGetter("yResolution")})
 private String yResolution;
```

Without this metadata the json string that will be created will be with all lower case letters

Found it here
[Custom serialized and deserialized field names with lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886553/custom-serialized-and-deserialized-field-names-with-lombok)