# Custom serialized and deserialized field names with lombok

Tags: json, jackson, lombok

Is there a way to specify different serialized/deserialized JSON field names without having to write out both getter and setter methods explicitly, perhaps using lombok getters and setters?

As similar to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8560615/922348), the following code permits incoming JSON to be deserialized to a different POJO field name. It also causes the POJO field name to be serialized as is:

```
public class PrivacySettings {
    private String chiefDataOfficerName;

    @JsonProperty("CDO_Name__c")
    private void setChiefDataOfficerName(String chiefDataOfficerName) {
        this.chiefDataOfficerName = chiefDataOfficerName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("chiefDataOfficerName")
    private String getChiefDataOfficerName() {
        return chiefDataOfficerName;
    }
}
```

This seems verbose, but I haven't been able to get this to work with @Getter and @Setter.  I did see that Jackson supports @JsonAlias which would probably help in this particular example, but I also have need to serialize with a different name.

Seems like this should be very simple, something like:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class PrivacySettings {
    @JsonSetter("CDO_Name__c")    
    @JsonGetter("chiefDataOfficerName")    
    private String chiefDataOfficerName;
}
```

But of course this is not valid.

Comment: The idea you share looks good but I reckon the example link you shared is the only supported way of doing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I particularly don't see anything wrong with a getter and a setter for this situation.

---

However, if you want to try, since v0.11.8 Lombok supports an [experimental feature](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX) to add annotations to generated getters and setters. See the [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter):

> To put annotations on the generated method, you can use `onMethod=@__({@AnnotationsHere})`; to put annotations on the only parameter of a generated setter method, you can use `onParam=@__({@AnnotationsHere})`. Be careful though! This is an experimental feature. For more details see the documentation on the [onX](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX) feature.

The syntax for this feature depends on JDK version. For JDK 8, you'll have:

```
public class PrivacySettings {

    @Setter(onMethod_ = { @JsonSetter("CDO_Name__c") })
    @Getter(onMethod_ = { @JsonGetter("chiefDataOfficerName") })
    private String chiefDataOfficerName;
}
```

For JDK 7, the syntax is:

```
public class PrivacySettings {

    @Setter(onMethod = @__({ @JsonSetter("CDO_Name__c") }))
    @Getter(onMethod = @__({ @JsonGetter("chiefDataOfficerName") }))
    private String chiefDataOfficerName;        
}
```

For further details, check the [`@Getter`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/Getter.html) and [`@Setter`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/Setter.html) documentation. Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38058913/1426227) for details on `@__()`.